# On mouseover fade embedded img or target specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible with js / jQuery to fade just the embedded image instead of the div in order to reveal the divs background image? I have multiple instances of the classes below and only want to affect change to the one's that are selected.

e.g:

```
.image {
    width: 200px;
    background-image: url(elements/pattern.png);
}

<div class="box">
        <div class="image"><img src="pics/001.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="project">Title</div>
</div>



$('.image').mouseover(function() {  $(this img).stop().animate({opacity:.7}, 200); });
$('.image').mouseout(function() {  $(this img).stop().animate({opacity:1}, 600); });
```

Also, is it possible to address specific classes within a div ?

e.g:

```
$('.image').mouseover(function() {  $(**this .project**).css({color:'#FFF'}); });
$('.image').mouseout(function() {  $(**this .project**).css({color:'#999'}); });
```

Thanks

....

**SOLVED**

Managed to get it to work by using find() as suggested and wrapping the image in an extra class. Now the image fades and .image's background pixel pattern blends through:

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="image"><div class="p"><img src="pics/001.jpg"/></div></div>
        <div class="project">Title</div>
</div>

$('.box').mouseover(function() {  
     $(this).find('.p').stop().animate({opacity:.3}, 200);
     $(this).find('.project').css({color:'#FFF'});
});

$('.box').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('.p').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 600);   
    $(this).find('.project').css({color:'#FFF'});
});
```

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's built in fade

```
    $('.image').hover(function() {  // on mouseover 
         $(this).stop().fadeTo(200, 0.7); 
    }, function(){                  // on mouseout
         $(this).stop().fadeTo(600, 1); 
    });
```

- [jQuery fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

Also to address specific items in a div you can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('.box').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).find('.image').animate({...}); // will animate .image when you hover .box
});
```

Comment: fadeOut() will set opacity to 0. OP wants to fade to 0.7. So better would be to use fadeTo()

Comment: I would use Toggle rather than fade, preference only of course

Answer (score 0):

You can use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$('.image').mouseover(function() {  $(this).next('.project').css({color:'#FFF'}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) attribute of the jQuery selector.

Basically:

```
$('.image').mouseover(function() {  $('img',this).stop().animate({opacity:.7}, 200); });
```

This would select the img element inside the element where the mouseover is triggered.

Comment: "Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $( "span", this ) is equivalent to $( this ).find( "span" )." And so it's better (but doesn't impact performance here) to use directly .find()